# How to compute the action probabilities with Thompson sampling in deep Q-learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, deep-rl, dropout, thompson-sampling

In some implementations of off-policy Q-learning, we need to know the action probabilities given by the behavior policy $\mu(a)$ (e.g., if we want to use importance sampling).

In my case, I am using Deep [Q-Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning) and selecting actions using [Thompson Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_sampling). I implemented this following the approach in ["What My Deep Model Doesn't Know..."](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/yarin/blog_3d801aa532c1ce.html): I added dropout to my Q-network and select actions by performing a single stochastic forward pass through the Q-network (i.e., with dropout enabled) and choosing the action with the highest Q-value.

So, how can I calculate $\mu(a)$ when using Thompson Sampling based on dropout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how can I calculate $\mu(a)$ when using Thompson Sampling based on dropout?

The only way I could see this being calculated is if you iterate over all possible dropout combinations, or as an approximation sample say 100 or 1000 actions with different dropout, to get a rough distribution.

I don't think this is feasible for practical reasons (the agent will learn so much more slowly due to these calculations, you may as well abandon Thompson Sampling and use epsilon-greedy), and you will have to avoid using importance sampling if you also want to use action-selection techniques where there is no easy way to calculate a distribution.

Many forms of Q-learning do not use importance sampling. These typically just reset eligibility traces if the selected action is different from maximising action.